# How to add a DateField to a mobile.form.Form or mobile.dialog.Dialog?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Can someone please tell me how to add a DateField to a mobile Dialog or to a mobile Form.

Or, frankly, to any other mobile ui class.

I've tried to  add a DateField to a  mobile.form.Form and mobile.dialog.Dialog with zero success.

Ive tried the following so far:

1) In the MobileShowCase Form.js file I did this:

```
qx.Class.define("mobileshowcase.page.Form",
{
extend : qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage,

__createForm: function()
{
    ...
    var form = new qx.ui.mobile.form.Form();
    form.add(new qx.ui.form.DateField());
    ...
}
```

The result is that the form is not renders.

2) In the MobileShowCase Form.js file I did this:

```
qx.Class.define("mobileshowcase.page.Form",
{
extend : qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage,

_initialize:function()
{
    ....
    this.getContent().add(new qx.ui.form.DateField());
    ....
}
```

The result is that the form is not renders.

3) In a file I called MyDialog that I copied (and simplified) from MobileShowCase Dialog.js I did this:

```
qx.Class.define("mobileshowcase.page.Form",
{
extend : qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage,

_initialize : function()
{
    ...
    this.__modaldialogpopup= new qx.ui.mobile.dialog.Dialog(new qx.ui.form.DateField());
    ...
}
```

The result is that the Dialog does not appear. Not even the button to launch the dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert a qx.ui.form.DateField into a qx.Mobile form.

Just insert a qx.Mobile text field and try alter the value with a qx.Mobile picker.